# Headers in OperationContext

Tags: c#, wcf

I'd make a little project (WCF + REST) and I have a small problem. I want make my Authorization and Authentication class.

My Authorization class:

```
//validate api key
public class BasicAuthorization : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    public override bool CheckAccess(OperationContext operationContext, 
        ref Message message)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

My Authenticate class

```
// validation user login & password
public class BasicAuthentication : ServiceAuthenticationManager
{
    public override ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy> Authenticate(
        ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy> authPolicy, Uri listenUri, 
        ref Message message)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

I have too some config file

```
<behavior>
  <serviceAuthorization 
      serviceAuthorizationManagerType="WCF.BasicAuthorization, WCF"/>
  <serviceAuthenticationManager 
      serviceAuthenticationManagerType="WCF.BasicAuthentication, WCF"/>
</behavior>
```

The code in class is unimportant - is not a problem.

My problem is how to get Headers from operationContext or message class. How i say before, i make this in rest, so i want manual set Authorizaion header / www-authenticate header, but application doesn't see it.

I turn on the Fiddler2, and try put any header for example :

```
Content-Type: application/xml
Authorization: Basic bla23rwerfsd3==
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:59305
```

And the message.Headers / operationContext.Headers doesn't has any my header (has only other one), no Authorization, no Content-Type

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Have you found any solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 14):

You can access the headers during your web-operation using the System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext class, which has a static property "Current", which represents the current-context. It provides an "IncomingRequest" property that contains a "Header" property of type "WebHeaderCollection".

Comment: It works. We also need to add reference to System.ServiceModel.Web system assembly as well.