# OData and ApiKey url-parameter through ServiceReference

Tags: c#, odata, service-reference

ApiKey is used to control the usage and it is affixed as an url parameter (implemented using somewhat modified version of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481894/how-would-you-implement-api-key-in-wcf-data-service)). Question is, how to go about appending this parameter when consuming the API through the use of the ServiceReference in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work just fine if you use the full URL to the $metadata in the Add Service Reference dialog in VS. So for example http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/$metadata?apiKey=1234 works, and it does send the query string as specified.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer on [social.msdn.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/adodotnetdataservices/thread/226c47f7-f7bc-4450-8dff-e1136e8404ba). Basically, you need to use the AddQueryOption method of a resource proxy, like:

`SomeService.SomeResource.AddQueryOption("apikey", "1234")`