# Api Keys in Query String with WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services, restful-authentication

I'm using query string based api keys for my WCF Data Service. I can handle this on the server pretty easily -- [How would you implement API key in WCF Data Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481894/how-would-you-implement-api-key-in-wcf-data-service)

However, how do I send the extra query string arguments from the client, using the Add Service Reference feature of VS2010? I saw an example for doing it when querying, but certainly not when adding/updating objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

- Add it to the "query string" via `.AddQueryOptions ()`
  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646860.aspx
   and example
  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/adodotnetdataservices/thread/226c47f7-f7bc-4450-8dff-e1136e8404ba
- Use `DataServiceContext.Credentials`
  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.credentials.aspx
   and
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.aspx
- Use the `Request header`
  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg258441.aspx
  and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.sendingrequest.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, `.AddQueryOptions` won't work with `.SaveChanges` / updates. How would `Credentials` help with query string parameters? It seems like my only option is the `SendingRequest` event.

Comment: there are several API key implementations possible with WCF - I wasn't sure what you implementation exactly is... so provided all methods I know of in this case...